# Would the Disguise Self spell benefit Stealth checks made to hide?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stealth

The [*Disguise Self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self) spell description says "You make yourself [...] look different until the spell ends". So, assuming a woodlands setting, and your "different" includes basically turning yourself into a bipedal bush, wouldn't this then increase your bonus to Stealth checks made to hide?

Obviously, this spell is not *Invisibility*, nor would any benefit to Hide have an affect on creatures that don't rely primarily on sight...but it makes sense that this could boost Hide rolls and I'm looking for input.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Perhaps; it is up to the GM.

The spell itself doesn't mention this scenario, so the only benefit you could gain from it is one granted by the GM. The [rules for ability checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage) mention:

> The DM can also decide that circumstances influence a roll in one direction or the other and grant advantage or impose disadvantage as a result.

In these situations, if the GM decides that your creative use of the spell warrants it, you could gain advantage on the Dexterity (Stealth) check involved in the Hide action.

### Keep your arms in mind.

While you can certainly change to appear to be rounder, and have leaves and the like...

> You can ... appear thin, fat, or in between... the extent of the illusion is up to you.

you still have arms to contend with:

> You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.

Obviously, you could try to position yourself to minimize the visibility of those arms, but that could be a factor in your GM's decision. You appear as a bipedal bush with arms.

Comment: Bipedal bush with arms...yeah, that belongs here Bob. Let's keep on moving.

Comment: Even without changing shape, they could *Disguise Self* to have camo-patterned skin.

Comment: @MikeQ Sort of a spell-based Mask of the Wild?

Comment: @NautArch: sort of? More like, instead of a beard, hanging green moss...instead of a head w a hat, ivy covered twigs. Just as successful real life camouflage (ghillie suits, et al) obscures the human shape and confuses the eye w natural colors, my thought is that Disguise Self easily could do the same, probably even better.

Comment: My take is use Disguise Self to have a ghilie suit

Answer (score -4):

### Hiding? No. Stealth? Yes.

Hiding is a specific system. Hiding is generally used in combat where every creature is assumed to be detect everyone else. The goal of hiding is to be undetected. If you are aware that someone looks like a bush, their cover is already blown.

However, stealth has a far wider scope. It includes things like "concealing yourself from enemies". This would be a great fit for bush disguises.

### DM Rulings

DMs are encouraged to make rulings that make sense to them, so if the player hides behind a wall, and uses disguise self, then edges out somewhere else into the woods, it may be reasonable for them to rule that the disguise is effective. Be aware that disguise self has vocal and somatic components, so even if you hide, when you cast a spell everyone will know.